# Data structure for fast lookup with multiple criteria

Tags: swift, data-structures

I have multiple elements that contain n properties. I need to create a datastructure that will return all the matching elements for a given set of criteria. The lookup needs to be fast.

To make it a bit clearer, imagine the following class:

```
class Element {
    let a : Int? // criterion0
    let b : Int? // criterion1
    let c : Int? // criterion2

    let value : String
}
```

Now I populate a `dataStructure` with 3,000 of such elements:

```
dataStructure.add(Element(a:1,b:3,c:4, value:"val0")) // insert 1
dataStructure.add(Element(a:nil,b:1000,c:40, value:"val1")) // insert 2
dataStructure.add(Element(a:nil,b:3,c:4, value:"val2")) // insert 3
...
dataStructure.add(Element(a:10,b:3,c:23, value:"val2999")) // insert 3000
```

And I will have to look up elements that could be exact matches to what I inserted, but that could also be different. Because of the wildcard nil, there could be many matches for each lookup. I need these look ups to be fast:

```
dataStructure.getAllMatching(a:4, b:30, c:4)
```

where a `nil` argument in the inserted element means that any value is a match.

For example `dataStructure.getAllMatching(a:1, b:3, c:4)` will return ["val0", "val1"] at least given what I inserted above.

Note that I have little constraint on memory, and I can spend some time at launch time to set things up. Only the lookup needs to be fast.

Comment: I think 300 elemens should always be filtered fast, almost independent from the algorithm.

Comment: Have you looked at using the "Mirror" protocol? If your object inherits from this protocol, it may make it easy to quickly loop through the properties of the objects as you use a `map` function on the array. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror

Comment: @JohnAyers thanks. This would make it easy, but I don't think it would make it fast

Comment: Something I would consider as you get these responses is that XCTest and XCTestCase support measuring the time it takes for various functions to run.  Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure.  It measures the number of seconds a block of code takes to run.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I saw that. It is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed number of fields (3 in your example), there's a straightforward way to do it which allows adding, removing and querying operations all in O(1) time. It uses O(n) memory but with a relatively large constant factor; this is OK if you have little constraint on memory. I'll write in a non-programming-language specific way since I don't use Swift.

Maintain a dictionary where each combination of fields, including wildcards, maps to a set of `Element` objects. This is probably easiest to describe by an example: suppose the elements are:

```
X = (a=1, b=2, c=3)
Y = (a=1, b=3, c=4)
Z = (a=2, b=3, c=4)
```

Then your dictionary is like:

```
{
    // just a
    (1, nil, nil): {X, Y}, (2, nil, nil): {Z},
    // just b
    (nil, 2, nil): {X}, (nil, 3, nil): {Y, Z},
    // just c
    (nil, nil, 3): {X}, (nil, nil, 4): {Y, Z}}`.
    // a and b
    (1, 2, nil): {X}, (1, 3, nil): {Y}, (2, 3, nil): {Z},
    // a and c
    (1, nil, 3): {X}, (1, nil, 4): {Y}, (2, nil, 4): {Z},
    // b and c
    (nil, 2, 3): {X}, (nil, 3, 4): {Y, Z},
    // a, b, c
    (1, 2, 3): {X}, (1, 3, 4): {Y}, (2, 3, 4): {Z}
}
```

Essentially, the data structure just stores the answer to every possible query (except those with no results).

To add or remove an element requires updating the sets belonging to 2^3 - 1 = 7 keys, and possibly adding a new key with a new set, or removing a key. If hashtables are used for the dictionary and the sets, the relevant dictionary/set operations all take O(1) time, and the number of such operations which need to be done is O(1), so adding or removing from the data structure takes O(1) time.

To query by some combination of field values, simply look up the query in the dictionary, and return the corresponding set (or return an unmodifiable view).

---

All of this said, for only 300 elements it is worth comparing the "naive" solution where you just store the elements in a list and check the whole list for each query. 300 is not a large number, perhaps not large enough for O(1) vs. O(n) to matter. Depending on programming language, other details like branch prediction and the CPU cache could have more effect than theoretical complexity. I'd recommend benchmarking both options.

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually edited it as I meant 3,000 and not 300. I have thought about this solution. Actually if I generate all the possible cases, I think the memory footprint is way more than O(n), since the number of possible sets (that are the values of your dictionary) is a sum of the combinatorials. Though memory is not a big issue, I don't think I can afford that.

Comment: Since `Element` has a fixed number of fields (3 in this case), the memory usage is linear because each element exists in exactly 7 sets, so total sizes of all sets added together is always 7n, and the total number of sets is at most 7n. It grows exponentially in the number of fields, but that is a constant.

Comment: If you have more than 3 fields, you can use less memory by only storing sets for combinations of, say, 2 or 3 fields, then if a query is on more fields you can do a dictionary lookup for the first three fields in the query, and then a linear search for the rest of the fields in the query. The set returned by the first query should be a small fraction of the 3,000 elements, so the linear search should be fast unless there are a lot of collisions.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that the elements that I have to look up are not a subset of the elements in the data structure. This is because of the nil criterion. In your answer, you are only allowing me to find exact matches. I'll edit my question to make it clearer what I mean. Your answer is valid for a slightly different use case.

Comment: @DevShark After reading your edit I'm not seeing the problem. For example, in my example the query `(nil, 3, nil)` would correctly return `{Y, Z}`. Can you give me a query involving `nil` on my example where you think the wrong result would be returned?

Comment: Sorry, I got it the wrong way. Actually the elements inside can have a nil value as argument, but when doing the lookup, the element we look for cannot have nil.

Comment: and so because of that, I don't think we can create all the possible keys upfront, because the integer set is unbounded.

Comment: @DevShark I think this solution can be adapted, and it's not necessary to insert infinitely many keys into the dictionary because you can look up multiple keys per query. It's not as straightforward as the original question was, but it should be possible. I'll think more about it another time.