# How to faster search an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a better way to search an array of objects as my current method is much too slow. I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    fname: 'r7942y9p',
    lname: 'gk0uxh',
    email: 'afit9og@gmail.com',
    phone: 2326571226
  },
  {
    fname: 'hipnr9f6',
    lname: 'rsnse5',
    email: 'ryv47qi@gmail.com',
    phone: 7863302156
  },
...
```

I want to search its objects by `email` and `phone` and return the first object that has a given phone OR email.

Question: Is there a faster way than

```
const log = data.find(item => {
    return (item.email && item.email === email) || (item.phone && item.phone === phone)
});
```

I have put together this simple benchmark:

```js
const data = [];
let r = len => Math.random().toString(36).substring(len);
let n = (min, max) => Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min));

for(let i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
    data.push(
        {
            fname: r(5),
            lname: r(7),
            email: `${r(6)}@gmail.com`,
            phone: n(10000000000, 20000000000)
        }
    )
}

const email = 'sdklhfldkf@gmail.com', phone = 19027931232;

console.time('search_time');
const log = data.find(item => {
    return (item.email && item.email === email) || (item.phone && item.phone === phone)
});
console.timeEnd('search_time')
console.log(log ? 'Found':'Not Found')
```

In the benchmark above the `data` array is filled with 50,000 random elements and is being searched for email or phone. My node server gives me the execution time of about 2.5 ms. Which means that if were to search the `data` array 10,000 times, which is very common, I have to wait for about 25 seconds. I would like to accomplish that faster (by however much I can)

Note that the presence of `phone` or `email` field is not guaranteed in the `data` array, hence `(item.email && item.email === email)`

Comment: What you're doing is `O(n)`. There isn't anything you can do to *significantly* speed things up, I think.

Comment: You could do some pre-processing to store the data in an object, and use the `phone` and `email` as a key for instant lookup. This will take up a fair amount of memory and isn't very scalable for many keys (more on this idea: [Data structure for fast lookup with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59994614)). Maybe consider storing this data in a database of some sort, which are usually optimized for this sort of searching

Comment: What @CertainPerformance said — unless your data is pre-sorted in a known way, you're going about as fast as you can get. If your data is sorted you could use a different algorithm though, like a binary search.

Comment: just sort your array by email, and run binary search by email. it will be a significant speed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok with preprocessing and using about the same amount of memory as data again, consider precomputing a lookup object (e.g. an index).

```js
// Use lodash
const emailIndex = _.invertBy(data, 'email')
const phoneIndex = _.invertBy(data, 'phone')
```

Indexing is about 40 times slower than searching with your method.

Here is your benchmark again:

```js
const data = [];
let r = len => Math.random().toString(36).substring(len);
let n = (min, max) => Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min));

for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    data.push(
        {
            fname: r(5),
            lname: r(7),
            email: `${r(6)}@gmail.com`,
            phone: n(10000000000, 20000000000)
        }
    )
}

const email = 'sdklhfldkf@gmail.com', phone = 19027931232;

console.time('indexing_time');
const emailIndex = _.invertBy(data, 'email')
const phoneIndex = _.invertBy(data, 'phone')
console.timeEnd('indexing_time')


console.time('search_time');
const log = emailIndex[email] || phoneIndex[phone]
console.timeEnd('search_time')
console.log(log ? 'Found' : 'Not Found')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I must say that this option ain't bad. As you point out, the sorting itself is rather laborious, but that's actually acceptable under my circumstances. Because there are occasions when the `data` array is searched 10k 20k 50k times, spending a little time indexing it prior to that is an excellent idea. I appreciate the input.